# Pandas conditional group by and sum

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, sum

Is there a way I can do a groupby and sum on some rows of a DataFrame, but leave the rest as is? For example I have the df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],
'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'two', 'two', 'one', 'three'],
'C' : np.random.randn(8),
'D' : np.random.randn(8)})
```

It looks like:

```
     A      B         C         D
0  foo    one  0.469112 -0.861849
1  bar    one -0.282863 -2.104569
2  foo    two -1.509059 -0.494929
3  bar  three -1.135632  1.071804
4  foo    two  1.212112  0.721555
5  bar    two -0.173215 -0.706771
6  foo    one  0.119209 -1.039575
7  foo  three -1.044236  0.271860
```

And now I'd like to groupby/sum the rows where the value in `B` is `one` (and keep the last occurrence in the column `A`). So the output would be:

```
     A      B      sumC      sumD
1  foo    two -1.509059 -0.494929
2  bar  three -1.135632  1.071804
3  foo    two  1.212112  0.721555
4  bar    two -0.173215 -0.706771
5  foo    one  0.030545 -4.005993
6  foo  three -1.044236  0.271860
```

How can this be done?

Comment: I am a bit confused, so position of last group `one` is not important? Can you change expected output by accepted answer?

Comment: No it's not important. I could just sort the rows if I wanted to. Accepted answer works perfectly, I don't mind where the last group `one` is, as long as it's summed.

Comment: Ok, thanks for explanation. So my answer will be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use this:

```
pd.concat([df.query('B != "one"'),
           df.query('B == "one"').groupby('B', as_index=False)['A','C','D']
             .agg({'A':'last','C':'sum','D':'sum'})])
```

Output:

```
     A      B         C         D
2  foo    two  0.656942 -0.605847
3  bar  three  1.022090  0.493374
4  foo    two -1.016595  0.652162
5  bar    two -0.738758 -0.669947
7  foo  three  0.913342  1.156044
0  foo    one  0.590764 -0.192638
```

Answer (score 0):

Another kind-of workaround is to define a new column that is a constant (e.g. `-1`) if `B` is `one` and a unique value (e.g. a range) otherwise, then group on it.

```
df['B2'] = np.where(df['B']=='one', -1, np.arange(len(df)))
df.groupby('B2', as_index=False).agg({'A': 'last', 'B': 'max', 'C': 'sum', 'D': 'sum'}).drop('B2', axis=1)
```

This avoids doing computations that in the end you throw away (although, if you really want to avoid these things, probably the easiest thing is just to split your DataFrame in two, where `df.B == 'one'` and where `df.B != 'one'`, work only on the former and then concatenate the results back)